# Which is the gcd of 2 numbers which are multiplied and the result is 600000?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

When 2 numbers are multiplied the result is 600000.Which is the greatest common divisor?
I think it might be 200.but also might be number 1.Can you help me please?

Comment: start with prime factorization of $600000$

Comment: This problem is not well stated. There are many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

This depends on the numbers. For example, $1 \times 600000 = 600000$ and then $1$ is the gcd, or $2 \times 300000 = 600000$ and $2$ is the gcd.

Are you looking to pick the numbers with the greatest gcd? If so, consider that the prime factorization looks like
$$
600000 = 2^6 \times 3 \times 5^5.
$$

How do you take the 2 factors so the gcd is maximal?

Comment: Happens to all of us.

Comment: We don't know who these factors are.so I guess a general solution for every possibility might be number 1.But isnt it called the lowest common diviser then?

Comment: @LedjaNushi yes, but something tells me you should be looking for the combination of numbers with the greatest gcd possible...